# I'm dying a lot at the start. How do I survive the beginning?

Tags: everspace

I started a new game but I'm dying constantly.  I get into a fight and I'm dead in 10 seconds.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I survive in this game?

Answer (score 1):

The game doesn't explain too much to you, so sometimes you will die and have no idea what you did wrong.  This is in line with the goal of the game being a space combat rogue-like.

Here are couple tips to get you started

- Do not fight the Okkar ships.  They are quite strong.  Go hunt some Outlaw Scouts.
- When Okkar Interceptors show up, this is your 1 minute warning.  The things that show up next will kill you.
- You can get G&B to kill Okkar ships.  Perform evasive maneuvers in front of some G&B fuel tanks so the Okkars blow one up.  All the units that were in the fight will stay hostile to any Okkar ships that gets near.
- Don't save your missiles.  Drop their shield and fire off 2-3 missiles to kill something quick.  There are much better missiles later.
- Use your Energized Boost whenever your shields are low, since using it will remove all your shield anyways.  If you lose all your shield, your starter shields take 10 seconds to begin charging again.

Last of all, there is no shame in dying.  If you come across a bunch of cash at the first stage, you might as well boost into a rock and die to spend it on perks.  You really need to get some perks to survive for all 7 sectors.

Comment: Did you get this from a website?

Comment: The tips?  No, it's from anecdotal experience, and seeks to address issues raised in reviews of the game being "too hard".  It's a hard game if you play it like a shooter and not a rogue-like.

Comment: The single best thing I learned was "use the strafe controls". If you're constantly changing direction, they can't hit you nearly as easily. (On a gamepad, it's the left joystick. Swirl it in a circle when you're going straight towards/away from enemies, and all will be well. Especially useful if you've just bitten off way more than you can chew, and are desperately trying to jump out: point yourself at the jump target, swirl the strafe, and you'll probably live.)